# How can I effectively restrict myself access to certain websites on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security, internet, blocking

I want to restrict access to myself and I know how to do it using Hosts file but it can be easily disabled by editing this file. Is there a way to effectively restrict myself access to this file after listing the websites that I want to block?

I've found some ways to restrict access to a file folder to a guest user but I'm the administrator on this PC and I'm the only one using this computer.

I also tried different blocking softwares like FocusMe, which blocks website after it's already loaded and it's not very reliable, it's totally possible to go to a website and download a file before FocusMe blocks it. Basically it looks at the actual text in the URL and if it matches a website in the blocklist, then it blocks it.

There is one software called CurrentWare (I think it was called BrowseControl in the past?) which has obviously more advanced algorithm because it doesn't even let you visit the website (unlike FocusMe) but it's not intended for one computer use and it's not designed to restrict access to yourself, plus the pricing is more suitable for lot of users. So using its algorithm for my user only for my computer would be ideal but haven't found such powerful software yet.

Comment: @dsstorefile Exactly. Since hosts file need admin rights it wouldn't be easy to just modify the file without permission

Comment: @dsstorefile Because the whole point of blocking websites is not to procrastinate and there are times my willpower isn't strong enough to leave it alone, so I want to ensure I won't be able to reverse the blocking.

Comment: Since you're administrator of the PC, you'll always be able to undo the restrictions you've created yourself. It's a question of how long and inconvenient the removing of restrictions will be.
Since hosts file isn't enough, try to restrict the same websites on your network router or call your Internet provider and ask them to block the websites for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to block websites to other members' computers in my family. What I'm looking for, can certainly be done because FocusMe has a great algorithm which makes it impossible to stop running and Fiddler and CurrentWare have great algorithms for blocking websites. If only these features were available together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of FocusMe, Cold Turkey and Hosts file. If anyone has a better solution, I'm still open to it.

Answer (score -1):

i believe the best way to block access to certain websites is by doing the following:

1. Using Google Chrome, install the following extensions:

   - Bloksi: With this extension you can block websites by category. It is very effective blocking the categories
     you select. It also allows you to set a password if you want to restrict yourself from modifying the settings.
   - Tiny Web Filter: With this extension you can block websites by keywords. It will quickly read the content of the
     websites and if it contains the keywords you want to block, the entire site will be blocked. It
     also can be protected with a password.
   - Site Blocker: This extension allows you to easily block any website by hitting right click and "Block this Site". It is very useful because you can block websites without the password, but if you want to allow the website, you will need the password. You also can password protect
     the settings of this extension.
   - Parental control: With this extension you can force chrome to search only in safe mode.
2. As you know, extensions can be easily removed from chrome, so your next step is to force the extensions installation.
   [How to block un-installation of extensions in Chrome/Chromium, using ExtensionInstallForcelist?](https://superuser.com/questions/1328465/how-to-block-un-installation-of-extensions-in-chrome-chromium-using-extensionin)
   With this guide you can easily block users from uninstalling your extensions. For this, you have to modify the registry, so you have to be
   very careful and create a backup of your registry.
3. Now that your Chrome is ready, you have to block yourself from using other browsers. For this, you can use a firewall like Comodo Internet Security. With this you can 
   create rules and only allow the programs you want to use the internet. In the Comodo website you can find a guide to do that (It is easy to do). You can also password protect the Comodo settings.
4. Install AnviFolderLocker to block yourself from manually uninstalling the Google Chrome Applications, Focusme or Comodo, by using the Read Only and Hide options. This software is free and
   can be password protected.
5. As you are the only person using the computer, you can disable the switch user option, because newly created users will lose the chrome extensions configurations.
6. Force youtube and Google safesearch in registry. This is also very easy to do through the registry.
7. Block access to registry so you cant modify the changes. There are various options to do this, but remember to save a backup of your registry.

If you need help with any of this, let me know and i'll help you.

Comment: Are all five of these extensions and programs necessary? If not, in which situations does each one apply?

Comment: What benefits does this have over [musicinmusic's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1314275/670755)?