# How to block un-installation of extensions in Chrome/Chromium, using ExtensionInstallForcelist?

Tags: windows-registry, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, chromium, productivity

In order to prevent de-installation of the chrome extension "stayfocusd" In a windows 10 pc with both Chrome 
Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) and chromium Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) installed, I took the following steps:

1. Downloaded the synced version of Chromium from: https://chromium.woolyss.com/
2. Went to: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/ and installed stayfocusd
3. Pressed start, typed> "regedit">enter
4. In the registry browsed to:
   `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies`
5. Right mouse Button (RMB) clicked on "Policies"
6. Clicked: New>Key>
7. Named the new Key "Google"
8. repeated the process untill I created the following path in the registry:
   `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist`
9. Then in the white field next to it RMB>New>string value
10. Named the string `1`
11. Gave the string the following value:
    laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji 
    (That is the 32 character-ID of the stayfocusd extension)
12. repeated the process for the following folder in the registry:
    `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist`
13. Yielding:

[This picture but then for both folders to illustrate the process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tahgp.png)

14. Closed Chromium
15. Rebooted the pc.

Then I opened Chromium again, but I was still able to uninstall stayfocusd without any problems.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I did wrong, or what I forgot, or another way to prevent de-installation of the stayfocusd extension?

Problem analysis:

0.
Currently I think the problem might be that I do not add a reference to the location where the stayfocusd extension is hosted as in some of the examples of the documentation is done [here](https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist):

> Windows (Windows clients):
>   Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist\1 =
>   "gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp;**https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"**
>
> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist\2 =
>   "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"

However I do not understand/cannot find how to supply that equivalent link for the stayfocusd extension. And I would think that its source to perform a re-installation should not be a determining factor in whether it would be able to prevent de-installation, but that is an assumption, which I am currently not able to test because I did not find that equivalent hosting link yet.

1. Another cause of the problem might be that I had to manually create the policy folders for google, which could be an indication that the chromium browser does not look at that location for its policies at a different registry location.

To test this I have searched for the "ExtensionInstallForcelist" but was unable to locate the folder in the registry before I had manually created them.  Now that I have created them I do not know how to continue searching after it finds the first instance that I have created, so I cannot check if there is an additional location where the "ExtensionInstallForcelist" folder existst which I did not create.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Preventing un-installation of any webstore extension in Chrome, not Chromium. Using the example of stayfocusd!: 
I am currently not sure if step 1 is needed, you can first try it without step 1 to see if it works. If it does please leave a comment with confirmation or not.

1. As explained in:
   https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist
2. downloaded the following templates from:
   https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates
   "ZIP file of ADM/ADMX/JSON templates and documentation"=
   https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip
3. copied:

`C:\Users\<Your username>\Downloads\policy_templates\windows\admx\en-US\chrome.adml`
`C:\Users\<Your username>\Downloads\policy_templates\windows\admx\en-US\Google.adml`

to:

`C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US`

and

`C:\Users\<Your username>\Downloads\policy_templates\windows\admx\chrome.admx`
`C:\Users\<Your username>\Downloads\policy_templates\windows\admx\google.admx`

to:

`C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\`

2. Then opened 
   Local Group Policy Editor with:

`start>"run">gpedit.msc`

3. `Computer Configuration>Administrative tools>add/remove templates>add`

opened:

`C:\Users\<Your username>\Downloads\policy_templates\windows\adm\en-US\chrome.adm`

4. That adds the "Google" folder in the subfolder:

`Computer configuration\Administrative Templates\`

Yielding

`Computer configuration\Administrative Templates\Google Chrome`
`Computer configuration\Administrative Templates\Google Chrome - Default Settings(user can override)`

5. Then opened:

`Computer configuration\Administrative Templates\Google Chrome\Extensions`

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XjEz.png)

6. in the window on the right (still in Local Group Policy Editor) I double clicked:
   Configure the list of force-installed apps and extensions
7. Then in the new popped up window I changed:

`Not Configured` 
to:

`Enabled`

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cEGW.png)

8. In the "Options" Pane, I clicked `add`, or `show`:
9. In the value screen I added the following value(s) (ID(s) of the extension I want to force Install)
   **Stayfocusd:**
   `laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`
   requestly
   `mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`
   ad block plus
   `cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`

   *Note that just the ID without hosting url: laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji does NOT work. 
   (Also if you are on a windows computer that is not part of a domain you cannot apply this method to InstallForceList extensions
   that are not in the Chrome Webstore.)

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3EhY.png)

10. then I rebooted the system
11. The policy can be checked by browsing to: 
    chrome://policy

there you should see the InstallForceList extension.

---

Now that you cannot un-install the extensions anymore