# A truly strict site blocking extension

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, blocking, productivity

I recently installed an app named *AppBlock* in my android phone. The thing I like about the app is that it has a **strict mode** which once activated will not let you change the settings of the app and *neither will allow you to remove the app* till the time duration of the strict mode expires. I am sure there must be a way to bypass the strict mode, but I do not want to know.

But I could not find any site blocking extension for chrome which has quite the same feature. The extension *StayFocusd* has a **nuclear option**, similar to the strict mode of *AppBlock*, but even with the nuclear mode on it is very easy to remove the extension just by clicking on its icon and hitting *remove from chromium*.

So my question is: Is there a site blocking extension out there which will not allow you to remove it for the stipulated period of time? Or is there some trick that you know which achieves the desired goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ExtensionInstallForcelist](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) to stop user uninstalling or disabling an extension.

> Specifies a list of apps and extensions that are installed silently, without user interaction, and which cannot be uninstalled nor disabled by the user.
>
> For Windows instances that are not joined to a Microsoft® Active Directory® domain, forced installation is limited to apps and extensions listed in the Chrome Web Store.

The methods for specifying the extensions vary by OS - Windows uses registry while OSX and Linux use preference file.

The varying locations are described here : [delevoper.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions).

> **Linux**
>
> /opt/google/chrome/extensions/
>
> /usr/share/google-chrome/extensions/
>
> **Mac OS X:**
>
> For a specific user: ~USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/
>
> For all users: /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/ 
>    /usr/share/google-chrome/extensions/
>
> **32-bit Windows:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
>
> **64-bit Windows:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not ale to figure out how to actually use ExtensionInstallForceList. I found this but it is for windows pc while I am using ubuntu 16.04: https://superuser.com/questions/1328465/how-to-block-un-installation-of-extensions-in-chrome-chromium-using-extensionin Can you please say a few words as to how to use ExtensionInstallForceList.

Comment: Added link describing location/procedure to install preference file.  The required data is in the first link as examples.